Can I use the PR validation build for release in Azure Devops Server?
We have a branch policy requiring a pull request and validation using a pipeline.   This does a merge with master, runs the pipeline to verify the build, and then waits for approval and completion of the pull request.  After this occurs, the changes are actually merged into master, the master reference is moved to the new commit, and the build occurs again as part of our CI.
Is there a way to use the output of the PR validation build instead of running the build again?   It seems wasteful.   If the master branch is updated by another PR, the build validation has to run again.   It seems like it is impossible to have a contents of the master branch that differ from what was used to build for PR validation.
I tried looking through documentation for azure-pipelines.yml and didn't find anything.   Since the pipeline was created using that, I don't see any settings in Azure Devops Server that could do it.   The only settings for the build pipeline are 'Processing of new run requests', 'YAML file path', and 'Automatically link work items included in this run'.

As per the appearance, you are using the build pipeline as the build validation in Branch policy, meanwhile you have CI trigger in build pipeline which will trigger it again after PR merge.
What you need to know firstly:

During the build validation pipeline run, the source repo is a dummy one:  {repo}@refs/pull/{pullrequestid}/merge， but after PR merge, the build pipeline targets on master branch to run, which is different.

Trigger in different way: The build validation policy queues a new build when a new PR is created or changes are pushed to an existing PR that targets the branch. After PR merge, the build pipeline runs only when a change is pushed to the target(master) branch(CI trigger).

As mentioned in the doc, Build policies help even if you're using continuous integration (CI) on your development branches to catch problems early.



Is there a way to use the output of the PR validation build instead of running the build again?

Hence, you need to consider if the build pipeline is still needed as build validation and build pipeline has different usage.
If the build pipeline is really not needed, you can remove the CI trigger in build pipeline(use trigger: none in yaml to achieve), so that it won't be triggered again after PR merge.
If you have artifact(output) in the pipeline, you can still consume the artifact in the release pipeline as before.

@Jason, PR validation run will help to catch problems early before your build run. As mentioned above, you can skip the build run, you can still consume the artifact output from PR validation run in another run, eg: release pipeline. Let me know if you have any queries.
